# Changing height of view inside UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I want to change the height of a `UIViewController's` view that is inside a `UINavigationController` to display a banner at the bottom so that it doesn't obscure anything.

I thought this would be pretty easy by just changing the view's frame in the `viewDidLoad` but that didn't work:

```
CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height - 49.0f);
```

I also tried to add

```
[navigationController.view setAutoresizesSubviews:NO];
```

after initiating the `UINavigationController` but it still looks the same.

The only option I can think of right now is to use the `UINavigationController` inside a dummy `UITabBarController` that will be obscured by the banner but that seems unnecessarily complicated to me.

Is there any way to change the height of the view controller's view inside a `UINavigationController`?

Comment: are you adding UIViewController to UINavigationController?

Comment: i think get some idea from this link.. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iAd_Guide/BannerAdvertisements/BannerAdvertisements.html

Comment: look at the layout constraints on your view.  By default they will fill the nav controllers space. Regardless of autoresizesubviews on the nav controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to change a view controller's view from within the view controller, but you could use a custom container view controller:

```
// Create container
UIViewController* container = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

// Create your view controller
UIViewController* myVc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];

// Add it as a child view controller
[container addChildViewController:myVc];
[container.view addSubview:myVc.view];
myVc.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleHeight;
myVc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, container.view.bounds.size.width, container.view.bounds.size.height-200);

// Add your banner
UIImageView* imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"banner"]];
imgView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleWidth| UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleTopMargin;
imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, container.view.bounds.size.height-200, container.view.bounds.size.width, 200);
[myVc.view addSubview:imgView];
```

Now you can add the `container` view controller to your navigation controller instead of your one.

Comment: It's more customizable tho (you can put your own views as the banner) and is also good if you don't have access to the view controller, like with a table view...

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 version of @jjv360 answer:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let myVc = UIViewController()
    
    self.addChild(myVc)
    self.view.addSubview(myVc.view)
    myVc.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    myVc.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: self.view.bounds.size.height-200)
        
    let imgView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "banner"))
    imgView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleTopMargin]
    imgView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.bounds.size.height-200, width: 
    self.view.bounds.size.width, height: 200)
        myVc.view.addSubview(imgView)
}
```