# Prevent view to cover navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, navigationbar

I push the new VC using `navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)`.
In `viewDidLoad` I set the view to a custom view:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  let clubDetailsView = ClubDetailsView()
  self.view = clubDetailsView
```

In the view itself, I set the background color to blue and it looks like it covers the whole screen. But I want it to be until the navigator bar starts.

[image]

Comment: Just wondering about your use case .. any reason for not adding your view as a subview to the main view ?

Comment: MVVM. Separating UI from the controller

Comment: I don't think you will break `MVVM` by adding 5 lines of auto layout code to configure the layout of your `ClubDetailsView` in your view controller. All the `ClubDetailsView`'s responsibility is still contained within its scope. If you still feel this is the way you want to go, it is going to be quite difficult, especially once you use navigation controllers. Here are some options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232214/changing-height-of-view-inside-uinavigationcontroller

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429127/change-uiviewcontroller-self-view-frame

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33156607/changing-uiviewcontroller-views-frame

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30683121/swift-change-uiviewcontrollers-view